# Weird visual glitches on ubuntu

Tags: graphics, minecraft

I run on intel celeron, which i managed to get minecraft running pretty good on.
i don't have a dedicated gpu, and there is no application i know of that can allow me to change settings to fix this.
I also know this is an ubuntu problem, not my cpu, because running mc in windows didn't have this problem, just fps issues.
I am using ubuntu 21.04 with the latest kernal.
here are some images which show the issues(for some reason something similar happens to selected text on firefox too).
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k54Ko.png)

[Minecraft issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcHvI.png)

[Better glitch image minecrarft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCM5u.png)

Comment: Your question should specify your release of Ubuntu, and the exact kernel you are using.

Comment: -fixed. I was using my phone at that point.

Comment: Really hope i can get it fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

i and many other people are having this issue following a kernel upgrade on ubuntu, still not sure how to fix this. i'm running 5.11.0-16-generic. There is a launchpad ticket i have opened [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/696627). What seems to be consistent is that this issue begins after doing a security/kernal/software update, and intel graphics is being run.

Comment: Is there a way to change the kerbal?

Comment: Is there a way to downgrade the kernal to one without this glitch?